# Copy/paste HTML table with colspan to Excel?

Tags: html, css, excel, google-chrome, copy-paste

**EDIT**: *On OSX, copy/paste works perfectly from Firefox, but not from Chrome or Safari*

Is it possible to copy table cells with colspan to Excel that reflects the structure?

Would like an app to render tables in HTML such that a user can copy/paste it to Excel reasonably well.  In particular, would like some table cells with `colspan=#` to copy to Excel with correct alignment.

The problem is that Excel seems to ignore colspan in copy/paste.  Thus in the example below the column title "Size" appears too far to the left, over the column for "Yellow" when it should appear over the column for "small"

I don't particularly care if the Excel cell is "merged", "centered across selection" or just plain separate cells.  They key thing is to have the position be semantically correct.

HTML5 okay as well as any hack

**CodePen**:  http://codepen.io/gradualstudent/pen/MYwNpY

*HTML table as rendered in browser:* 
[image]

*Table after copy/paste to Excel:*
[image]

Comment: Is it an option, copy&paste the HTML source code of the table? Try the following: Copy the HTML source code of the table from your CodePen. Then paste it into an Excel sheet with one cell selected.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant.  That works just fine. So I perhaps I can copy the HTML to the clipboard, rather than highlight the DOM element and have Chrome get the HTML to put on the clipboard.  I may ask you to post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clipboard handling differ in different browsers. Whether Excel can get a table from the clipboard in the correct format depends on which data have the different browsers put in the clipboard. Unfortunately the most actual operating systems comes not more with a clipboard viewer per default. So we cannot simply look there what the differences are.

But Excel can deal with HTML tables. And so if HTML source code of a HTML table is in the clipboard, then Excel can paste this properly.

Example with VBA:

```
Sub HTMLinClipboardTest()

 sHTML = "<table>" & _
         "<tr><td colspan=""2"" align=""center"">colspan2</td></tr>" & _
         "<tr><td rowspan=""2"" style=""vertical-align:middle;"">rowspan2</td><td>default</td></tr>" & _
         "<tr><td>default</td></tr>" & _
         "<tr><td>default</td><td>default</td></tr>" & _
         "</table>"

 Dim oDataObject As New DataObject 'needs Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
 oDataObject.SetText sHTML
 oDataObject.PutInClipboard
 ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```