# How to copy a HTML table with colspan to clipboard in an Excel compatible way?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, clipboard

The copy to clipboard example below demonstrates how one can copy a simple HTML table to the clipboard. Everything works more or less as expected and the table can be inserted into e.g. Apple Notes, Microsoft Word, ...; All applications respect the colspan and render the table correctly.

An issue arises when pasting this table into Excel. The colspan is simply ignored as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix or workaround this issue, such that Excel inserts the table respecting the colspan of the cells?

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const copyButton = document.querySelector('#copy');
const pre = document.querySelector('#pre');

copyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const content = {
   'text/html': table.outerHTML
  };
  navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem(content)]);
  pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(content);
})
```

```html
<table id="table" contenteditable="true">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">row 0, col 0 - 1</td>
      <td>row 0, col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1, col 0</td>
      <td>row 1, col 1</td>
      <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<br>
clipboard content:
<pre id="pre" style="overflow:scroll; width:inherit"><pre>
```

Comment: relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195643

Comment: I noticed that behavior seems to be different on Windows and MacOS, so these issues could be related to different behavior of the system clipboards and Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the columns and rows by copying the full HTML.

```
const table = document.querySelector("#mytable")
if (table) {
 const blob = new Blob([table.outerHTML], { type: "text/html" });
  const tableHtml = new ClipboardItem({ "text/html": blob });

  navigator.clipboard.write([tableHtml]).then(function () {
  console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
       }, function (err) {
         console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
       });
};
```